# Why use dispatch to call a function in actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

In my redux actions.js file i have the following two functions ::-

```
export const init = () => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: TYPES.SET_LOADING });
    await dispatch(getConfig());
    await dispatch(getGenres());    
    dispatch({ type: TYPES.REMOVE_LOADING }); 
}

export const getConfig = () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get('https://api.lala.org/3/configuration?api_key=370');
    dispatch({
        type : TYPES.GET_CONFIG,
        payload : res.data
    });
}
```

I am just confused as to what is the use of `await dispatch(getConfig());` ?

I understand when dispatch is used to send an `action` and a `payload` , but why is dispatch being used to call a function ? is it because dispatch is async and we need to use await ?

Comment: It is probably an async action of `redux-thunk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you have to dispatch an action, which is just an object with a type (e.g. `dispatch({ type: TYPES.SET_LOADING });`). With [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) as middleware, however, you can also use asynchronous functions with redux, e.g. for fetching data. Therefore, you pass the async function call as the parameter for dispatch (`await dispatch(getConfig());`). The async function needs to return another function which has now the dispatch function as the parameter (`const getConfig = () => async dispatch => {...}`.

In that async function you can then dispatch actions.